# Images not showing on html template Django python

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I have a template which has a source to an image, every time I run my html file the image does not display,I have tried some examples but to no success, I have set the url.py, settings.py and html file. Am new to Django.

URL.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from rulebase.rulesapp.views import myview
import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^rulebase/', include('rulebase.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^myview/$', myview),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
)
```

Settings file

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/dev/Django/rulebase/media/'

    MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/media/'

    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

HTML
`<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}logo-on-trans.png" width="448" height="255" />`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having the images served by Django's `STATIC_URL` and not `MEDIA_URL`.

Have a read of the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

It's as easy as:

- `STATIC_ROOT = ''`
- `STATIC_URL = '/media/'`
- `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/user/dev/Django/rulebase/media/',)`
- Remove the URL pattern for `'^media/...'` (no longer need it)
- Change the HTML line to `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}logo-on-trans.png" width="448" height="255" />` and providing that the file is inside the directory you've stated it should be served with the HTML.

Read the docs though, there's important justification for why.

Comment: I tried installing STATIC module this is the error it throws back.
`Error: No module named staticfiles` under installed INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: In `INSTALLED_APPS` there should be a line reading `'django.contrib.staticfiles' and if there's not then add it in.

What is the entire error that Django is giving you?

Comment: Thats the error its giving me no module.That line is not there. Am using 1.1.4

Comment: Django is on version 1.5.1 now, 1.1.4 is very out of date. [Upgrading to 1.5.1 should fix your issue.](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) (note you may also need to upgrade Python to the latest version.

Comment: Also: _dont_ use the '/media/' for `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` if you're `MEDIA_URL` is also '/media' <g>

Comment: Agreed. Each URL you define should be distinct regardless of whether or not it is in `settings.py` or `urls.py`

Comment: Did upgrading Django fix your problem?

Comment: Upgrading would fix it. But am restricted to use 1.1.4 and nothing more.

Comment: [This is the documentation for 1.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/static-files/) - try following this if you cannot upgrade to the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

delete and try index URL from main URLs file,
so the URL used in this manner url('',view=index),
empty between two quotes url, delete

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Caner Uysal.
As you are new, please consider reading the following topic which you can access in the Help Center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer